# How do I make my Sencha Touch 2 Button rectangular?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have tried and failed.  Anyone know how? Any method will do, css, javascript, or otherwise.

Comment: @hekomobile So now a have ONE solution... I changed one of the sass variables in my file ($include-border-radius: false;).  All buttons are rectangular now.  Thats a price I am willing to pay, but there has to be a better way.  Note to anyone who tries this: put this modification before the import all line in your sass file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create you're button just add a `style` attribute to the button like so :

```
{
  xtype:'button',
  text: 'Button',
  style:'border-radius:0'
}
```

You can also use the `cls` attribute to associate a CSS class to your button and then add the style in a separate CSS file linked to your HTML file.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

in your custom-theme.scss file, add the following line

```
$button-radius: '0px';
```

then compile the scss file using the command "compass compile".

This will do the magic for you.

Comment: This is the right way to do this.

Also worth noting it needs to go above:
import 'sencha-touch/default';
import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
if you're including those.